# How to count the total of a column in a specified interval of time for each month?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to count the total of a column in a specified interval of time (20:30-22:00) for each day or in alternative the average of that hour in a month, could you help me? Thanks.

With this query I can't have the total I need.

```
Select COUNT (Qt_Tot_CallType)
from [Reporting].[dbo].[TLC_STAT_INBOUND_CC]
where (CONVERT(char(19), Dt_Rif, 20)BETWEEN '2019-01-01 20:30' AND '2019-01-31 22:00') AND (Cd_Servizio IN (71,72,73,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,88,90,91,96,97,98,99,100,101,109,110,111,112,116,133,139,140,142,144,152,153,154,156,157,159,160))
group by (Dt_Rif)
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

count `COUNT(Qt_Tot_CallType)` is for the number or not null row with value in the column `Qt_Tot_CallType`

could be you need  a sum

```
  Select Dt_Rif, SUM(Qt_Tot_CallType)
  from [Reporting].[dbo].[TLC_STAT_INBOUND_CC]
  where CONVERT(char(19), Dt_Rif, 20)
       BETWEEN '2019-01-01 20:30' AND '2019-01-31 22:00' 
  AND Cd_Servizio IN (71,72,73,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,88,90,91
      ,96,97,98,99,100,101,109,110,111,112,116
      ,133,139,140,142,144,152,153,154,156,157,159,160)
  group by (Dt_Rif)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cast` your datetime column first as time

```
Select COUNT (Qt_Tot_CallType),  month(Dt_Rif)
from [Reporting].[dbo].[TLC_STAT_INBOUND_CC]
where cast(Dt_Rif as time) BETWEEN '20:30:00' and '22:00:00' AND (Cd_Servizio IN (71,72,73,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,88,90,91,96,97,98,99,100,101,109,110,111,112,116,133,139,140,142,144,152,153,154,156,157,159,160))
group by month(Dt_Rif)
```

Comment: that's good but i need the average of the sum of ALL Cd_Servizio for each month in the specified time

Answer (score 0):

Date and time ranges are best compared with `>=` and `<`. Make sure you compare them separately, because you don't want the range from `'2019-01-01 20:30'` till `'2019-01-31 22:00'`, but the days `'2019-01-01'` to `'2019-01-31'` and the time range `'20:30'` to `'22:00'` for each day.

Group by date (which you strip from the datetime) to get one result row per day. Use `SUM` for a total and `AVG` for the average.

```
select
  convert(date, dtrif) as day,
  sum(qt_tot_calltype) as total,
  avg(qt_tot_calltype) as average
from reporting.dbo.tlc_stat_inbound_cc
where cd_servizio in (...)
and dtrif >= '2019-01-01' and dtrif < '2019-02-01'
and convert(time, dtrif) >= '20:30:00' and convert(time, dtrif) < '22:00:00'
group by convert(date, dtrif)
order by convert(date, dtrif);
```